# Speed converting itertools.combinations in to a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of 1000000 items, and I used combinations of r=2, but it takes so long to loop over these combinations, is there a fast method to get these combinations?

```
x = list(range(1000000))
comb = itertools.combinations(x,r=2)
for i,j in comb:
    process(i,j)
```

Any suggestion!

Comment: There are half a trillion such combinations. At the rate of 10 million per second, it would take nearly 14 hours to go through them. Do you really need to process them all?

Comment: No, it's the best you can get.

Comment: It is unlikely to make much of a difference, but there is no need to covert `range(1000000)` into a list to get combinations from it. For larger ranges, using nested for loops rather than `itertools.combinations()` seems to give (according to `timeit` ) a very small speed boost, but unlikely enough to make what you are trying to do more feasible.